# Dynamically change database name programmatically Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, rename

I have an EF connection string in my config but I wish to programmatically change the dbname on the fly.

The properties appear to be read only - anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: [Connecting to database for Multi-Tenant application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717832/connecting-to-database-for-multi-tenant-application)

Comment: Look at the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class